# Why does this type of loop in node.js cause growing memory usage which lead to allocation failing?

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory

```
let val;
while (true) {
    val = Math.random()
    if (val != 0)
        console.log(val)
    else
        break
}
```

output:
[822:0x1a7f9a0]  1156633 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1425.5) -> 1396.9 (1425.5) MB, 920.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.258, current mu = 0.234) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[822:0x1a7f9a0]  1157779 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.8 (1425.5) -> 1397.0 (1427.5) MB, 912.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.231, current mu = 0.204) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

Comment: Is this intellectual curiosity or is this something you're really trying to use?  On the theory side of things (rather than a practical programming problem to solve), pretty much any synchronous `while` loop that does anything of consequence (causing objects to be allocated) that can run zillions of iterations may mess up a garbage collected system because there may be no cycles for garbage collection during the super long loop.

Comment: FYI, does your loop ever terminate?  I know that theoretically, `Math.random()` can return `0`, but the probably of it actually doing that is really, really, really low.  I'm seeing billions of iterations without it hitting `0`.

Comment: I've been told Math.random() would return 0 finally by Khan Academy. So I decided to have a try by myself. But before I got the expected result, it terminates and output error information as metioned. The reason I posted this question is that I'm learning C language recently, theoretically, I only declared 'var' once, so it shouldn't take memory space more than var itself. So I'd like to know whether there're some machanism that I've never learned @jfriend00

Comment: Well, you'd have to look into the implementation of `Math.random()` to see what it does internally.  It is creating a new floating point number on EVERY call to the function.  You then assign that to your one `var` which makes the previous floating point number eligible for garbage collection, buy still occupying memory until the garbage collector gets a chance to run.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for `Math.random()` to return zero, but the probability of it doing so, is really, really low so it may take a really, really long time before it does.  Meanwhile you fill up all your memory with all the previously allocated floating point numbers that all the previous calls to `Math.random()` allocated.  And, if `Math.random()` created any other objects internally while running, those will also be in memory and awaiting garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for your information. And I have a try with python, the memory usage is stable at a low value. So the behavior of nodejs' garbage collector seems a lit bit weird for me@jfriend00

Comment: Well, this isn't really very much like a real world problem since you generally wouldn't execute code like this (running a synchronous `while()` loop with trillions of iterations in the main thread before ever yielding).  So, what matters more is how the GC works with real world code.  I'm sure there are tradeoffs involved in exactly how/when GC works and therefore one particular experiment does not give you an overall evaluation of how GC performs.  I'm not attempting to offer any opinion on GC in nodejs vs. GC in Python, just saying you don't have a very complete picture from one test.